# Spring Gateway that generates JWT token

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to build a Gateway with spring-cloud. It should do some logic if a JWT exists, and it doesn't exist, it should create it (from scratch). I've got some example from internet and all of them are using oauth2, and I don't want it. 
Does anybody know from an example online similar what I'm talking about. I'm new with both spring-cloud-gateway and spring-security

I've tried the https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/16/securing-services-with-spring-cloud-gateway example, but I'm confused with all the oauth part.

Answer (score 1):

To issue (create) an JWT, you must **authenticate** the user, the JWT is cryptographically signed (by the authenticator) proof that the request is sent from that user.

### Separation of Concerns

**Gateway**

The concern of a Gateway is to route requests. And do that in a good way.

> Spring Cloud Gateway aims to provide a simple, yet effective way to route to APIs

**Authentication Service**

The concern of an Authentication Service is to authenticate the users, e.g. be the only service that has access to the user password metadata and be the only service with access to **private keys** used to sign **JWT** tokens.

The [separation of concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is the reason why these two components are designed as two different components. The gateway should not have access to the private key to sign JWT tokens, so it should instead *redirect* unauthenticated users to the Authentication Service (Single Sign On in your link).

Comment: I have some wired requirements for the user. I will need client certificates to authentificate. For each one properly authenticated I have to generate a token. I understand, when a user doesn't have a token he must be redirected to the client certificate token.   Once the user is in the system, the client wants that his 'session' never exipres, so each time a user connects to the system we will need to extend the expirantion date from the token. When we update the software, we will need to cancel his token and recreate a new one in order to make him access to the new version.

Comment: Out client doesn't want us to ask again for the client certificate, when we update the software. So the only solution I see, is that the API gateway has some control over the token in order to revoke one and recreate automatically.

Comment: @Elena as I see it, client certificates is only a way to _authenticate_ with the Authentication Service, e.g. instead of passwords. So the architecture will be the same as I describe.

Comment: my concern is, if I have to change the expiration time of the token with each http request, I need to redirect to the call to the Authentication Service in order that this component returns a properly signed JWT with a new expiration time.

Comment: Jonas, I know it is been a while but how gateway decides user is unauthenticated?